# Why doesn't request.on() work in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node-request

I'm trying to get some data from a third party service using the node request module and return this data as string from a function. My perception was that `request()` returns a readable stream since you can do `request(...).pipe(writeableStream)` which - I thought - implies that I can do

```
function getData(){
    var string;

    request('someurl')
        .on('data', function(data){
             string += data;
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            return string;
        });
}
```

but this does not really work. I think I have some wrong perception of how request() or node streams really work. Can somebody clear up my confusion here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work exactly the way you explained. Maybe the problem that you're facing is due to the asynchronous nature of node.js. I'm quite sure you're calling your `getData()` in a synchronous way. Try this and see if you're `request` call is not returning something:

```
request('someurl')
  .on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data.toString());
  .on('end', function(){
    console.log("This is the end...");
  });
```

Take a look at this piece of article [here](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks). It's not short, but it explains how to write your code in order to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The weird behavior was 1. because I didn't have the .toString() method so I got some strange looking output and 2. I was calling it as you said correctly synchronously. I'm not really sure how I should go about calling it asynchronously while being able to return the received data. The only Idea I can come up with is passing in a callback to the getData() function which gets called when the 'end' event is emitted and passing it the data `.on('end', funciton(){ callback(allData); })` Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Yeah, you got the point: callbacks. This is the "node way" of doing things. IMHO, this is how you should handle this: call the callback inside the `end` event.

Answer (score 1):

What I get is you want to access `string` later and you thought the `request` would return a completed string. If so, you can't do it synchronously, you have to put your code to process the completed `string` in the `end` event handler like this:

```
function getData(){
    var string;

    request('someurl')
        .on('data', function(data){
             string += data;
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            processString(string);
        });
}
getData();
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Yeah I figured this could be the problem. Can you maybe comment on my comment above? Wold passing in a callback be a good solution to get back the data anyway?

Comment: Callbacks is the most used solution to handle async code aside from pubsub/event, promises, generators, etc. You would learn about the horrible "callback pyramid" anytime soon and how you'll need a library to streamline your code before ES6 is coming. I need 50 reps to comment so I couldn't do that, sorry.