# MochaJs: I can't print/debug anything on screen

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

The `console.log` doesn't print anything on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
  describe('Hitting Google', function() {
      it("expecting to return something",function (done) {
          request.get("https://www.google.com")
          .on('response',function (result) {
              console.log('############');
              return console.log('Gone right');
              console.log('############');
          })
          .on('error',function (err) {
              console.log('############');
              return console.log("ERROR: ",err);
              console.log('############');
          });
          done()
      })
  });
```

**EDIT**

the problem is not with `console.log`, but for some reason, when I update the file and run it again, changes wont show effect, the mocha keeps printing the old file version, why is that?

Comment: What library are you using for `request`? Have you tried the `on('end', function(data){...})`
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477699/why-doesnt-request-on-work-in-node-js

Comment: Look at question update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is asynchronous so you call done() before you have a response back from the request.

Comment: so, what should I do? Not call it at all?

Comment: In any case you need to call done in both response or error events or on end event.