# How to run api that is dependent on variable set from first api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request

I am trying to create a node seed script from an api. The api displays in multiple pages and has a property called 'numberOfPages'.

On each page, I will be seeding a database. so, I intend on taking the 'numberOfPages' variable and running a for loop with the appropriate api response for X page. Currently, numberOfPages shows as undefined when ran through the .on function. It DOES show when I run it within the if statement below. What is the appropriate way to asynchronously do this?

```
"use strict"

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var request = require('request');

let key = 'MAGICNUMBER';
let baseRequest = "http://apiurl?key=" + key;


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase");
const db = mongoose.connection;
// mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));`
    function populateController(){
      let numberOfPages;
      request(apiRequest, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            let apiResponse = JSON.parse(body);
            numberOfPages = parseInt(apiResponse.numberOfPages);
        }
      }).on('end', () => {
        console.log('ended');
        console.log(numberOfPages);
      }) })
```

Finally, happy holidays.

Comment: as a sidenote, I am pretty sure I can run this for loop within the if statement, but it starts to feel really messy to me to be nesting this far.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316729/how-to-run-api-that-is-dependent-on-variable-set-from-first-api/41317336#41317336) below help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good for me, it should work. I've added some logging to your code.

```
function populateController(){
  let numberOfPages;
  console.log('Starting');
  request(apiRequest, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      let apiResponse = JSON.parse(body);
      numberOfPages = parseInt(apiResponse.numberOfPages);
      console.log('Result', numberOfPages);
    }
    else {
      console.error('Error in request', response.statusCode, err);
    }
  }).on('end', () => {
    console.log('Ended', numberOfPages);
  });
});
```

This should write this, or some errors.

```
Starting
Result 42
Ended 42
```

BTW async things are pretty messy. I recommend using async-await. You need to get used to them, and you can't leave Node callbacks completely. Even though, they might get things cleaner.

Plus related post: [Why doesn't request.on() work in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477699/why-doesnt-request-on-work-in-node-js) -- Watch out for synchronous / asynchronous execution order! Some logging can help you understand how is the execution order.

Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `request` don't parse the JSON by yourself (at least not without wrapping it in `try/catch` or using [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) because you risk crashing your app on bad data).

Also, make sure that you are already connected to the DB before doing the requests.

And also use explicit base in `parseInt`.

It's easier to divide your logic into steps if the asynchronous flow is confusing:

```
  db.on('connected', startRequests);

  function startRequests() {   
    request.get({
        url: apiRequest,
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
      }, (err, res, data) => {
        if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) {
          // handle error
          console.log('Cannot get number of pages');
        } else {
          // data is already parsed as JSON:
          console.log(data.html_url);
          handlePages(parseInt(data.numberOfPages, 10));
        }
    });
  }

  function handlePages(numberOfPages) {
    // you have the numberOfPages here
    console.log(numberOfPages);
  }
```